# Extending PagerRenderer and create other new methods ci4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to add extra methods for codeigniter4 **PageRenderer**, so I could be easy for getting counter number passed through the data attribute .
If I use my additional method directly to the PageRenderer class, everything run well, But If I want to put my extra methods through application Libraries.

```
//vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Pager/PageRenderer.php

<?php namespace CodeIgniter\Pager;

use CodeIgniter\HTTP\URI;

class PagerRenderer
{
}
```

So, within Libraries direcory I can be able to create a class that extends the PagerRenderer class which has extra custom function to extend some features like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Libraries;

use CodeIgniter\Pager\PagerRenderer;
class Pagination extends PagerRenderer
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    // Get First Page Number 
    public function getFirstPageCounter(): int{
       return (int) ($this->segment === 0) ? 1 : $this->segment; 
    }
     
    // get Last page Number
    public function getLastPageCounter(){
        return (int)($this->segment === 0) ? $this->pageCount: $this->segment;
    }
     
    // Get previous Page number
    public function getPreviousPageCounter(){
        if (! $this->hasPrevious()){ return null; }
        return (int) ($this->segment === 0) ? $this->first - 1 : $this->segment;
    }
     
    // get Next Page Number
    public function getNextPageCounter(){
        if (! $this->hasNext()){ return null; }
        return (int) ($this->segment === 0) ? $this->last + 1 : $this->last + 1;
    }   
}
```

And For using those methods inside pagination nav views it will be like this
inside App/Views/Pagination/pagination.php

```
//pagination.php
use App\Libraries\Pagination\
<?php $pager->setSurroundCount(2); ?>

<ul class="pagination">
    <?php if ($pager->hasPrevious()) : ?>
        <li><a href="<?= $pager->getFirst() ?>" data-page="<?= $pager->getFirstPageCounter() ?>"></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?= $pager->getPrevious() ?>" data-page="<?= $pager->getLastPageCounter() ?>"></a></li>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php foreach ($pager->links() as $link) : ?>
        <li <?= $link['active'] ? 'class="active"' : '' ?>><a href="<?= $link['uri'] ?>" data-page="<?= $link['title'] ?>"><?= $link['title'] ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>

    <?php if ($pager->hasNext()) : ?>
        <li><a href="<?= $pager->getNext() ?>"  data-page="<?= $pager->getNextPageCounter() ?>"></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?= $pager->getLast() ?>" data-page="<?= $pager->getPreviousPageCounter() ?>"></a></li>
    <?php endif ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: So what's the error you're seeing?

Comment: Some error from parent class I mean from the array injected as param inside  PagerRenderer class. __constuctor(array $details). so I get error of undefined pageCount and other variables.